# Transferring ArcGIS Server directories to another location (D drive) on AMI EC 2

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.1, amazon-ec2

Updated question:

I am using ArcGIS Server 10.1 + ArcGIS desktop 10.1 on AMI EC2 instance & I am facing space problem so trying to move existing server directories to different drive.

Currently our dept is under maintenance so I am copying “arcgisserver” folder (Currently it is on C:\arcgisserver) to my “D drive”.

So my question is that which things should I take care (like data ,rest service etc) ?

I am familiar with ArcGIS Server 10 and it was easy to perform above settings in 10.0 as compare to 10.1

Currently I am going through ESRI web help and researching on it

Any help will be great !!!  Thanks in advance : )

Comment: This looks like 4 questions so I recommend that you provide the same background but ask each question separately.

Comment: @PolyGeo thanks and I have updated my question : )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its resolved by creating new site.

Steps I followed :

1.Created new site (Same name as previous site name (arcgis).

2.Copied data inside the services folder (C:\arcgisserver\config-store\services to newly created folder on D i.e. D:\arcgisserver\config-store\services).

3.Logged out and Logged in.

4.REST and everything is working fine.

5.No need to restart AMI EC 2 instance.

Thank you all : )